# How insert data from a list to an empty column in SQL Server using pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql, list, insert, pyodbc

I have a list of string elements and I'm using pyodbc to insert these items into a column that I just created on SQL Server. I read many threads and tried many methods including cursor.execute() and cursor.executemany() but none has done the trick so far. Is there any other method or library to recommend?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with more details. Did you add this column to an existing table that already has rows in it? If so, how do you want to match the items in your list with the rows? Consider adding the table definition, sample data, and expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your message Gord, I created a table, I added a column using pyodbc. Now I want to fill the column with the data that is saved in a python list. For matching purpose, I was going to use the list index.